# Laravel Dusk attach multiple files to the same input

Tags: laravel, testing, file-upload, image-upload, laravel-dusk

I am trying to write some browser tests for a web app using `Laravel Dusk` and I have an input like this:

```
<input id="images" type="file"
        name="image_name[]"
        style="display:none"
        accept="image/*"
        @change="addFile"
        multiple="multiple"/>
```

I am trying to attach several files using this:

```
->attach('#images', base_path('/data/tests/media/images/incorrect_format.webp'))
->attach('#images', base_path('/data/tests/media/images/incorrect_size.jpg'))
->attach('#images', base_path('/data/tests/media/images/incorrect_dimensions.png'))
```

but instead of attaching each image once it attaches the first image 3 times, the second 2 times and the third 1 for a total of 6 attachments.

Here is a screenshot from dusk:

[image]

No idea why this is happening. Googling various things to do with Dusk attaching multiple files reveals nothing. Any ideas?

EDIT 1: Attaching the full test class. The revelant part starts after "// test incorrect images format, dimensions, and size":

```
<?php

namespace Tests\Browser;

use App\User;
use Laravel\Dusk\Browser;
use Tests\Browser\Pages\Login;
use Tests\DuskTestCase;

class BeaconsTest extends DuskTestCase
{
    public User $user;

    protected function setUp(): void
    {
        parent::setUp();

        $this->user = User::factory()->create(['country' => 'Bulgaria']);
    }

    public function test_beacon_form_errors(): void
    {
        $user = $this->user;

        $this->browse(function (Browser $browser) use ($user) {
            $wrongDataMsg = 'Es gibt einige Fehler. Sehen Sie sich die Formularfelder für den genauen Fehler an.';
            $fieldIsRequiredMsg = 'Dieses Feld ist erforderlich.';
            $incorrectImageFormatMsg = 'Muss eine Datei des Typs: jpg, png, gif sein.';
            $incorrectThumbnailDimensions = 'Das Bild muss genau 300 x 300 Pixel groß sein.';
            $min1200x900Msg = 'Das Bild muss mindestens 1200 x 900 Pixel groß sein.';
            $incorrectFileSizeFrontendError = 'Die Datei hat die maximale Dateigröße überschritten.';
            $incorrectFileSizeBackendError = 'Darf nicht größer als 5 Megabyte sein.';

            $browser->visit(new Login)
                    ->loginUser($user)
                    ->assertSee('+ Neues Beacon')
                    ->click('@create-beacon-link')
                    ->waitForLocation('/beacons/new')
                    ->assertSee('Neues beacon')

                    // test some incorrect data
                    ->click('@save-as-active')
                    ->waitForText($wrongDataMsg)
                    ->within('@minor-wrapper', function($browser) use ($fieldIsRequiredMsg) {
                        $browser->assertSee($fieldIsRequiredMsg);
                    })
                    ->within('@title-wrapper', function($browser) use ($fieldIsRequiredMsg) {
                        $browser->assertSee($fieldIsRequiredMsg);
                    })
                    ->within('@body-wrapper', function($browser) use ($fieldIsRequiredMsg) {
                        $browser->assertSee($fieldIsRequiredMsg);
                    })

                    // test incorrect thumbnail dimensions
                    ->type('minor', rand(1, 65535))
                    ->type('title', 'A new title')
                    ->attach('#thumbnails', base_path('/data/tests/media/images/small_dimensions.jpeg'))
                    ->assertSee($incorrectThumbnailDimensions)
                    ->click('@save-as-active')
                    ->waitForText($wrongDataMsg)

                    // test incorrect thumbnail format (webp)
                    ->attach('#thumbnails', base_path('/data/tests/media/images/incorrect_format.webp'))
                    ->assertSee($incorrectImageFormatMsg)
                    ->assertSee($incorrectThumbnailDimensions)
                    ->press('@save-as-active')
                    ->waitForText($wrongDataMsg)
                    ->assertSee($incorrectImageFormatMsg)

                    // test incorrect thumbnail file size
                    ->attach('#thumbnails', base_path('/data/tests/media/images/too_big_size.jpg'))
                    ->within('@thumbnail-wrapper', function($browser) use ($incorrectFileSizeFrontendError) {
                        $browser->assertSee($incorrectFileSizeFrontendError);
                    })
                    ->press('@save-as-active')
                    ->waitForText($wrongDataMsg)
                    ->within('@thumbnail-wrapper', function($browser) use ($incorrectFileSizeBackendError) {
                        $browser->assertSee($incorrectFileSizeBackendError);
                    })
                    
                    // test incorrect images format, dimensions, and size
                    ->attach('#images', base_path('/data/tests/media/images/incorrect_format.webp'))
                    ->within('.images-wrapper .image-input-wrap > div:first-child', function($browser) use ($incorrectImageFormatMsg) {
                        $browser->assertSee($incorrectImageFormatMsg);
                    })
                    ->attach('#images', base_path('/data/tests/media/images/1200x899.png'))
                    ->within('.images-wrapper .image-input-wrap > div:nth-child(2)', function($browser) use ($min1200x900Msg) {
                        $browser->assertSee($min1200x900Msg);
                    })
                    ->attach('#images', base_path('/data/tests/media/images/too_big_size.jpg'))
                    ->pause(15000)
                    ->within('.images-wrapper .image-input-wrap > div:nth-child(3)', function($browser) use ($incorrectFileSizeFrontendError) {
                        $browser->assertSee($incorrectFileSizeFrontendError);
                    })
                    ->press('@save-as-not-active')
                    ->waitForText($wrongDataMsg)
                    ->within('.images-wrapper .image-input-wrap > div:first-child', function($browser) use ($incorrectImageFormatMsg) {
                        $browser->assertSee($incorrectImageFormatMsg);
                    })
                    ->within('.images-wrapper .image-input-wrap > div:nth-child(2)', function($browser) use ($min1200x900Msg) {
                        $browser->assertSee($min1200x900Msg);
                    })
                    ->within('.images-wrapper .image-input-wrap > div:nth-child(3)', function($browser) use ($incorrectFileSizeBackendError) {
                        $browser->assertSee($incorrectFileSizeBackendError);
                    });
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you attach your Dusk test class full source

Comment: I don't think you can with dusk

Comment: @Lk77 wow that would be a major feature missing

Comment: @PetarVasilev it's seems, by looking at the doc, it looks like we can only add one file with attach()

Comment: @Lk77 why does it add 6 then?

Comment: Found a way that works. In my case each subsequent call to ->attach attaches the current image plus all the previous ones. So in the frontend after loading each image just do: `e.target.value = ''` on the file input and that clears the old images so that they are not added on subsequent calls.